# caused by : message in logcat not showing the position of cause of crash in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

When i started using Android Studio (at that time latest build was 0.3.2), It used to show the 
class and line number of the cause of nullpointerException. But since i have upgraded a few times to the lastest release, I only get this line  in stead of the message that used to pinpoint the line causing the app to crash because of NullPointerException.

`W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416f3c80)`

do i need to configure something or there is no solution?

it used to show something like this

```
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):    at com.tec.araj.Myda$Myhelper3.onCreate(Myda.java:44)
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):    at com.tec.araj.Myda.open(Myda.java:18)
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):    at com.tec.araj.MainActivity$Mytask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:101)
01-12 17:35:12.215: E/AndroidRuntime(25757):  .........
```

**EDIT**

my biuld.gradle had these lines

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: I never observed this, in Android Studio 0.4.2 I am able to see the line number and everything about my NUullPointerException occurrence.Add the code in your question where null pointer exception occuring and AS not showing the Line number and class.

Comment: Perhaps you're running a release build or you've disabled debugging info your debug build.

Comment: @ScottBarta I don't know but even i use `debuggable false` in my build.gradle file. When i filter my logs with error i am able to see my `NullPointerException` error. I do this in my code `String a=null; a.contains("a");` for test. I am not able to see process in left DDMS panel but Exception logs are there in logs, Is it correct ?

Comment: @ScottBarta humm . I just check and found that in build.gradle I was using release. as shown in the edit of question.

Comment: A simpler question to ask is if you have any sort of filtering on your logcat view; check that. If you run logcat from the command line and not from inside Android Studio, is it any better? If it is, then look to see what's going wrong in your filtering.